# Text Clustering - Extracting meaningful title / description from the clusters generated

Tags: clustering, k-means

I use k-means algorithm to cluster my data(multiple reviews of an app). I need to generate meaningful sentences which will describe each of the cluster.

One approach that I tried was to find the data point(s) closest to the centroid and use its title. But I am looking at something that will capture the context of the clusters more efficiently.Can some one help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: That never worked well for anybody. ;-) There is absolutely no guarantee that there is only one topic in the cluster, so how could there be a single meaningful title that isn't "A and B and C and D"?

Comment: Oops, but since the very purpose of clustering is to group similar text together , I assume the titles should be talking about the same thing ( my results do verify this point). I still can't generate a title which represents everything about the cluster.. ( thanks for letting me know it's not been easy :) )

Comment: We tend to think we're seeing patterns when we look at text clusters. But that is quite biased. You'll easily find very similar titles that are not in the same cluster, too. (Search for an article called "reading tea leaves")